# Swift How to update (modify, Delete, Add) entries of JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

Hello i need some help here, I'm making an IOS app that gets data from a JSON API and then showing the results on a Table , when i tap on a result from the table it goes to a second view controller where i'm showing the details. What I want to do is to update the info I'm showing on the details, delete entries from the JSON by deleting them from the table itself, and add a new entry to be saved on the JSON.

This is the JSON structure:

```
      {
        _id: "57eec6c9dfc2fb03005c0dd0",
        ssid: "nonummy",
        password: "accumsan",
        lat: 29.39293,
        lon: 115.71771,
        summary: "curae nulla dapibus dolor vel est donec odio justo sollicitudin ut",
        __v: 0,
        likes: 1,
        unlikes: 0,
        bssid: "EF:CD:AB:56:34:12"
        },
```

I want to be able to update the SSID, Password and Summary.

this is the code I'm using to get the Result from the JSON and is working good

Code:

```
       let url = URL(string:"https://fierce-peak-97303.herokuapp.com/api/wifi")!

       let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error)

        }else {

            if let urlContent = data {

                do {

                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)

                //print(jsonResult))

                    for item in(jsonResult as? NSArray)! {

                        let ssid = (item as? NSDictionary)?["ssid"] as? NSString

                        //print(ssid)

                    }
                    self.tableData = jsonResult as! NSArray

                    DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {
                    self.table.reloadData()
                    })

                }catch {

                    print("No Json Result Was Found")
                }

            }

        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

For example if I click on one line of the table I want to be able to update password.

Comment: after you get the json as an object, you can write over the values that you want to, then write over the original json file with your new data.

Comment: Map the data to a custom struct

Comment: Could you show me how to write over the values, please i got the Json and i see the results i couldn't figured out how to update de values :(

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it like this : all formatted for swift 3

```
       //declare parameter as a dictionary which contains string as key and  value combination.
    let parameters = ["ssid": newSSID.text!,"password": newPass.text!,"lat": newLat.text!,"lon": newLon.text!,"summary": newSum.text!] as Dictionary<String, String>

    //create the url with NSURL
    let url = URL(string: "https://fierce-peak-97303.herokuapp.com/api/wifi")

    //create the session object

    let session = URLSession.shared

    //now create the NSMutableRequest object using the url object

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"


    var err : NSError?
    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
    }catch{
        print("error")
    }

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        print("Response: \(response)")
        let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("Body: \(strData)")
        var err: NSError?
        do {
            var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary

        }catch{

            print("JSON error")
        }

        // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
        if(err != nil) {
            print(err!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
        else {
            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary

                if let parseJSON = json {
                    // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
                    let success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int
                    print("Success: \(success)")

                }
                else {
                    // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                    print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
                }

            }catch{

                print("JSON error")


            }

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the contents of the json file as whatever data structure you want, then overwrite the values that you want to change and finally overwrite the original file when you want to save your changes:

So you're already getting the JSON as an array:

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)

let array = (jsonResult as? NSArray)!
```

So now you can just change the values in array, when you're done changing everything you want then you can overwrite the json file: (swift 3.0)

```
var jsonData: NSData!
// serialize json dataa
do 
{
    jsonData = try JSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(array, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print(jsonString)
} 
catch let error as NSError 
{
    print("Array to JSON conversion failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

// overwrite the contents of the original file.
do
{
    let file = try FileHandle(forWritingToURL: url!)
    file.writeData(jsonData)
        print("JSON data was written to the file successfully!")
}
catch let error as NSError
{
    print("Couldn't write to file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

I'm not sure exactly how writing to a server works, but since it's a URL i think it should act the same way.

Update:

So your original array is:

```
let array = (jsonResult as? NSArray)!
```

You can cast it to an array of dictionaries like so

```
var dictionaries : [[String: NSObject]] = array as? [[String: NSObject]]
```

and you get ssid by doing:

```
int i = 0;
for (dictionary in dictionaries)
{
    let ssid = dictionary["ssid"]
    let newSSID = ssid + "something I want to edit my values with"

    // now we have our new value, so we update the array
   dictionaries[i]["ssid"] = newSSID
   i += 1
}
```

now after this we just overwrite the original file with the new dictionaries object, which I wrote out above.

Comment: I followed what you recommended but still not getting the result i want.

Comment: For example i get the results from one Entry of the table SSID , password and summary , maybe is easy but i don't see it :(

Comment: Hello i just update the code like you said but i'm getting this error message

Comment: var dictionaries : [[String: String]] = (array as? [[String: String]])!
**Tread 10: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(Code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0   , sorry for all the questions i'm just learning how to do this, i don't know how to post an image here too :(

Comment: What are the types for the dictionary? Are they String: String? or is it something else? Try changing the Dictionary type to String: Object

Comment: This is JSON data 
      _id: "57eec6c9dfc2fb03005c0dd0",
       ssid: "nonummy",
       password: "accumsan",
       lat: 29.39293,
       lon: 115.71771,
       summary: "curae nulla dapibus dolor vel est donec odio justo sollicitudin ut",
       __v: 0,
       likes: 1,
       unlikes: 0,
       bssid: "EF:CD:AB:56:34:12"
When i'm getting de JSON results this is the definition 
                            let ssid = (item as? NSDictionary)?["ssid"] as? NSString         don't know what is missing

Comment: Did you try changing the type of the dictionary to String: Object?

Comment: That means you have to change the dictionary line to this: var dictionaries : [[String: NSObject]] = array as? [[String: NSObject]]

Comment: I guess something is not right, because i want to change a single entry and it shows all  , using the what you recommended with the NSObject is not showing the error but when i'm trying to update the newSSID variable with something else it's not doing anything, Here is what i want to do: when i click on any element of the table it takes me to another view where i can see the details ( SSID, Pass and Summary), if i click on a edit button, i display a textfield where i can type something so that's the string i want to insert or update in the JSON and then the Table. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Here's the idea: you convert your json file to the dictionary shown above and keep a reference to it. Now, when you click and edit your text field, you change the corresponding field in the dictionary. After the user hits save or is done editing (whichever you prefer) you use the json saving code snippet I provided to save the dictionary with all the new values to the same file you loaded it from. To debug and make sure you're actually getting all the right values I would print out all the fields you're loading into your table view.

Comment: Anyways I think that this is getting off topic, I've shown you how to load, modify, and save to a json file like you've asked.

Comment: Yeah I know i appreciate your help, I'm still learning and there are things that I'm still trying to figure out anyway I'll try again there is something maybe I'm doing wrong